# Как убрать лишние строки в excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, nan

Сравниваю 2 таблицы excel данной конструкцией:

```
result = df1.loc[df2.ne(df1).any(axis=1)]`
```

вывожу результат:

```
with ExcelWriter(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', mode="a") as writer:
                    result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="лист1", header=None, index=False)`
```

в третью таблицу, но он выводится с лишними строками

[image]

Как можно их убрать и привести к такому виду?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод результирующей таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как выглядит result до экспорта в эксель? И как вы его экспортируете?

Comment: @CrazyElf  "И как вы его экспортируете?" дополнил вопрос. 

"А как выглядит result до экспорта в эксель?"  если вы про то как выглядят данные в таблицах перед сравнением то так же как и на первом скрине. Сразу скажу отступ в таблицах сравнения убрать нельзя.

Comment: вас спросили про результирующую таблицу ПЕРЕД экспортом в excel. как она выглядит?

Comment: @strawdog уточните нужны данные которые выводятся в консоль print(result4)?

Comment: Ну например да `print(result)`. Хотя я что-то не пойму - сколько у вас этих `result`-ов, откуда взялись `result2`, `result4`, если изначально в коде был только `result`?

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнил вопрос таблицей, по поводу result поправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам мешают `NA` значения, можете их просто выбросить:

```
result = result.dropna()
```

Но вообще мне кажется вы изначально как-то не так выборку делаете. Мне кажется правильно делать так:

```
result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
```

А у вас получается, что из `df1` производится выборка по позициям в `df2`, поэтому и получается, что по каким-то строкам просто нет булевой маски для выборки через `.loc`, отсюда и возникают `NA` значения.